# Use java awt drawRect from a separate method?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, drawrect

I am attempting to draw Sierpinski's triangle on a pixel-by-pixel basis that resizes itself any time the window size is changed. I believe I have most of the project done but I don't quite know how to draw the rectangle from the separate recursive function that is outside of the paintComponent method.

```
public class SierpTriangle extends JPanel 
{
    public final int x = this.getWidth();
    public final int y = this.getHeight();
    public final int side = getsize();

    public int getsize()
    {
        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();
        if (width <= height) 
        {
            return width;            
        } 
        else 
        {
            return height;             
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawSierpTriangle(this.x, this.y, this.side);
        g.drawRect(x,y,1,1);
    }

    public void drawSierpTriangle(int x, int y, int size) 
    {
        if (size == 1)
        {
            //Draw rectangle? This is where I need help

            g.drawRect(x,y,1,1); //this does not work, passing Graphics g into the method also does not work
        } 
        else 
        {
            drawSierpTriangle(x/2, y, size/2);
            drawSierpTriangle(x,y/2,size/2);
            drawSierpTriangle(x/2,y/2,size/2);
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SierpFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the reference of `Graphics` from `paintComponent` to `drawSierpTriangle`

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    drawSierpTriangle(g, this.x, this.y, this.side);
    g.drawRect(x,y,1,1);
}

public void drawSierpTriangle(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size) 
{
    if (size == 1)
    {
        //Draw rectangle? This is where I need help

        g.drawRect(x,y,1,1); //this does not work, passing Graphics g into the method also does not work
    } 
    else 
    {
        drawSierpTriangle(g, x/2, y, size/2);
        drawSierpTriangle(g, x,y/2,size/2);
        drawSierpTriangle(g, x/2,y/2,size/2);
    }   
}
```

> This results in: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError at the first recursive call of the method. Any input?

```
public final int side = getsize();
```

will make `side` for ever `0`.

Replace it with something more like...

```
public int getSide() {
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();
    if (width <= height) {
        return width;
    } else {
        return height;
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int side = getSide();
    if (side == 0) return;
    drawSierpTriangle(g, this.x, this.y, side);
    g.drawRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}
```

This will evaluate `side` every time the component is painted.  It will also skip painting the shape if side is `0`

You'll also have the same problem with `x` and `y`, since there state is never changed

Comment: This results in: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError at the first recursive call of the method. Any input?

Comment: @flashield Verify the exit condition, is it possible for `size` to ever be `1`? Also, be careful, there's already a method called in `getSize` defined in `JPanel`